# Походження виразів «шпака вбити» і «шпака удрати»

Tags: значення-слів, фразеологізми, сталий-вираз

Цікавить походження чи логічне пояснення таких двох виразів:

1. *Шпака вбити*, що означає *схибити*.
2. *Шпака удрати*, що означає *здрімнути*.

Comment: *шпаками годований* - вередливий, перебірливий

Answer (score 0):

За однією з версій, ці вирази можуть бути пов'язані з давнім українським звичаєм називати різні дії тваринами. Так, "шпак" може використовуватись для опису дії схибити через схожість зі звуком, який виділяє птах під час польоту. А вираз "шпака удрати" може бути пов'язаний із звуком, який виділяє птах під час здрімання на гілці.

Інші джерела вказують на те, що в обох виразах може бути використаний образ шпака як птаха, який швидко рухається і має невеликий розмір, що може викликати асоціації з помилками або дрімотою.

Однак, точне походження цих виразів залишається невідомим, і вони можуть бути результатом різних міфів, легенд і народних прикмет.

Comment: Було б дуже круто, якби ви навели свої джерела тут. Можна з витягами найдоречніших фрагментів.